# Get the city geofence

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I'm working with google map and i want to draw a polygon that cover the boundary of specific city

example manila Philippines

[image]

I know how to draw a polygon on google map but the problem is data. Where to you think i can download data to draw a polygon that cover the boundary of the city.